# Multiple items at one page simplecart

Tags: simplecart

I've been struggling lately with my online shop, based on SimpleCart.

The problem is :

The main item is made from several smaller items. These smaller ones you can configure in many ways. What I am trying to do is that I don't want to appear the main item in the shopping cart as one thing. Instead I want the smaller ones to appear in the shopping cart.

i.e.
General page layout:
(main item name- does not appear in checkout)CAR

```
< span class="item_name">body:< span class="item_color"> red< span class="item_price">
< span class="item_name">wheels:< span class="item_color"> black< span class="item_price">
```

and soo on.

How I would like the shopping cart to look like:

```
name-----color-----price
body------red-------350,99
wheels---black----210,00
...
```

Basicaly, what I wanna do is to place several items at one site, and after click on 'Add to Cart' button I want them all to appear in a Shopping Cart(each in different row).